# Visual studio erorr

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

Okay so i installed cheat for apex legends, from github and when i open .sln file it says ,, One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctl. Please see the output window for details.

And i dont get ,, Build " Button and in the windo output says :

C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\hypervisor\hypervisor.vcxproj : error  :
Project "C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\hypervisor\hypervisor.vcxproj" could not be found.

What to do?
Can someone help me pleaseeee!

Comment: Don't cheat! :D

Comment: hahaha, but i need it hihih

Answer (score 0):

It seems you downloaded the sln file directly from github using your browser. That won't work. You need to download (or rather "clone") the whole repository instead. Clone the repository using git (You can use the Visual Studio Startup Window for that).